# Return data from custom Hook calling a graphql query

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

I am new to `graphql and react.`. Here , I have following method,

```
export const useName = (isRequest: boolean) => {
  const {
    nav: { id, idme }
  } = stores
  if (buyingSession) {
    const { data, loading,error}
    = usegroup(id, {
      fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network'
    })
  } else {
    const {data} = usesingle(idme)

  }
  return data;
}
```

//This function should return a string which will be in data object.But I am getting confused over here because its a query and it takes time so it returns undefined but when I checked in the network it gives response as well.

```
export const useme = (id: string) => {
  return useQuery(GET_ME, {
    fetchPolicy: "cache-first",
    skip: !id,
    variables: {
      id: id
    }
  }
```

In another component , I am calling ,

```
const data = useName(true)
```

So, this is the call which actually calls the graphql query. Now , when I am getting data it gets undefined.

How do resolve this issue ?